# Loading Images from a Directory Rather Than Individually In Javascript Var

Tags: javascript

edit --

I was able to figure this out however I only want to display .png files that are found in my directory. Is there a way to only show png files by adding something to this code?

```
<?php
  $path = 'testimages';
 $handle = @opendir('./' . $path . '/');
 while ($file = @readdir($handle)){
  if("." === $file || ".." === $file) continue;
  echo ', {' . "\n" . ' id: ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) .     ',' . "\n" . 'name: "Product ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . '",' . "\n" . 'imageUrl: "' . $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'thumbnailUrl: "' .      $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'openUrl: "' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file)         . '.html"' . "\n" . '}' . "\n";
}
@closedir($handle);
unset($handle,$file,$path);
?>
```

Comment: Javascript cant simply list directories, so you're gonna have to create a index of all files somewhere. You could perhaps use php&ajax to get the directory listing.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this with javascript due to security but you can use ajax to make a request to a server-side script, php for example to scan the directory and return all the file names...

Comment: Ah ok that would be why nothing I tried works. Thanks for the tips. I will try to figure out how to do it via ajax and php. Any examples of that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php found my starting point. thanks again

Comment: @Thomas I'm sure you can find many ajax examples online and how to scan a directory using php, it will just be a matter of putting them together :)

Comment: you can check this link for php https://gist.github.com/aslan144/2047603

Comment: Thanks I see you have a way to filter out only image files with $file_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); . Any idea how I can do that with the code above?